# Can iframe video go full screen in Chrome Webview in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

I have iframe url which has video (html5),

When i load the page in android webview it doesn't go full screen. Is it pausible to do it?

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.160:8080/");
```

Comment: Check this. i don't know if it will solve your problem though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179802/how-to-make-a-full-screen-webview

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `onShowCustomView'. See [this](http://www.go-dev.net/2012/03/android-play-html5-youtube-videos.html), for example.